# "Row handle is invalid" error, Excel, VBA, SharePoint list automation

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to automate population of a SharePoint list, but getting "Row handle is invalid" error.
My code:

```
Sub test() 
Dim cnt As New ADODB.Connection 
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 
Dim SQLstr As String

SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM [DB];"

With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "WSS;" & _
    "IMEX=0;" & _
    "RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
    "DATABASE=" & URL & ";" & _
    "LIST=" & ListID & ";"
    .Open 
End With

rst.Open SQLstr, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

With rst
    .AddNew
    .Fields(1) = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value
    .Fields(4) = ws.Cells(1, 2).Value
    .Fields(7) = ws.Cells(1, 3).Value
    .Update 
End With

End Sub
```

The error pops up on the `.Update` line.
I created a brand new SP list and the code works fine. But for some reason it doesn't work with the list I need it to work with.
Also, on both lists, I am able to use `rst.Find` Method and successfully update existing records. 
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you adding a new entry to the table? If so, can you use INSERT INTO [DB] ?

Comment: @pnuts they are list of products with mostly text fields and a few 'yes/no' choice fields. My test list is a replica of the original list, yet it behaves differently.

Comment: @RicardoA just tried your suggestion now, but I'm getting some inconsistent behavior - for the original list, I'm getting an error saying I didn't provide values for some required fields (not true cause I made sure I did). For my replica list (List2), it worked fine a couple of times, but then it started giving me the same error. None of the fields in List2 requires a value so not sure why this error pops up and why it didn't initially.

Comment: @pnuts apart from the fact that List2 doesn't require values be entered, they are identical. I had them side by side and made sure the settings, column order, field types, etc. match. My fields are single-line-of-text type. There are the default fields with dates, numbers, Created By, etc. that are added automatically to all lists, but their settings are locked so I'd imagine they'd be the same for both lists.

Comment: Are you providing the name for the Fields? Ej: INSERT into [DB] (Field0,Field1,Field4,Field7) VALUES (F0Value,F1Value,F4Value,F7Value)

Comment: @RicardoA I am, and also using single quotes for filed name with spaces

Answer (score 0):

I've just came across your post while I was in search of a similar question.

Did you check the SharePoint list mandatory fields? Few columns would automatically be marked as 'Required' (eg: Title column). Removing such criteria or including such columns in the code by passing a value would help. I hope this can fix your issue.